# Could someone recommend video tutorial websites for beginners?

Tags: python, ajax, video

I'm not sure what it is about me but I seem to learn and retain information better through a classroom setting where what's being shown is explained clearly and easy to understand examples are presented.  I rarely do my own reading or research, but I do occasionally stumble upon some neat things.  Maybe I'm just used to the classroom setting from all the years of the education process or it could just be the lazy man in me.

In any case, if anyone could recommend some video tutorial sites, particularly for beginners, that would be great.

I am particularly interested in the following...

- Web 2.0 (AJAX, XML, DHTML, Javascript, CSS, etc)
- Python

Of course, if anyone knows some sort of wide-range, general site for tutorials of all kinds to help programmers out there, that would be great too.

Thank you.

PS - For the purposes of my software development needs I've decided to give Eclipse a try as it seems to be one of the most widely used IDEs in the industry.

Comment: A few pointers, Web 2.0 is not a useful term as there are a million different definitions. AJAX is not well defined either, but it is at least just a combination of HTML/CSS, Javascript and some server side computation. DHTML is like AJAX 0.1, just HTML/CSS and Javascript.
And remember that Eclipse shines in the Java department, the rest (mostly) not so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Django (Python MVC framework) try [here](http://thisweekindjango.com/screencasts/)

For CSS try [here](http://cssvideos.com/)

For jQuery try [here](http://blog.themeforest.net/screencasts/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/)

For DHTML try [here](http://www.coffeecup.com/free-dhtml/help/tutorials/)

My advice don't go for eclipse if oyu are beginner use a texteditor. Eclispes features can be overwhelming for beginners.

Comment: Well I'm not a beginning programmer, just a beginner in those languages.

Comment: fair enough as someone who's used several sets of dev tools, I still found that eclipse had a higher learning curve as opposed to netBeans for example and I cut my first java teeth on Crimson editor. When I tried eclipse it was too much for me. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

MIT has a great Intro to Computer Science course using Python.

[MIT 6.00 Introduction to Computer Science and Programming](http://ocw.mit.edu/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-00Fall-2008/CourseHome/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

[ajaxprojects](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/newsdetails.php?itemid=26), [learning python through videos](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/learning-python-programming-language-through-video-lectures/), [python link](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/python) on showmedo, a video tutorial site where you can find many other topics being covered as well.

Answer (score 0):

http://pycon.blip.tv/

Answer (score 0):

[ShowMeDo(Python)](http://showmedo.com/videos/python) has plenty of screenscasts for the whole gamut of experience levels.